# posix_spawn with POSIX_SPAWN_SETEXEC enabled

Tags: c, macos, posix

OSX man page says about **POSIX_SPAWN_SETEXEC** bit in `posix_spawn` system call:

```
POSIX_SPAWN_SETEXEC
Apple Extension: If this bit is set, rather than returning to the caller,
posix_spawn(2) and posix_spawnp(2) will behave as a more featureful execve(2).
```

Anyone knows what exactly is the difference between a regular `posix_spawn()` and a `posix_spawn()` after a call to `posix_spawnattr_setflags` which enabled `POSIX_SPAWN_SETEXEC`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `POSIX_SPAWN_SETEXEC` is set, instead of spawning a new process, `posix_spawn` replaces the process just as `execve` would do.